# How do I profile an Enterprise Application using Netbeans & Glassfish?

Tags: java, netbeans, jakarta-ee, profiling, glassfish

As the title suggests, I am trying to profile an enterprise application, which is running in glassfish3 using Netbeans 6.9.1. Running normally, and using the debugger works fine. But when I want to profile the application I get the following error:

```
Target "compile-test-single" does not exist in the project "IDE". It is used from target "profile-test-single".
BUILD FAILED (total time: 0 seconds)
```

**NOTE**: `IDE` is the name of the project. It has nothing to do with "Integrated Development Environment"!

The project was created a few years back in NetBeans 5. To be on the safe side, I did a complete new checkout, removing all files which are auto-generated by NetBeans (`build.xml`, `nbproject/*`, ...). After that, I re-created a new "Enterprise Application with existing sources", which should re-create those files. And it did.

So now I should have the files just the way NetBeans should like them. Yet, I still get this error. Why is `compile-test-single` not created in the build.xml file? I grepped through the project folder, googled on the web, and still, I cannot find it.

Am I supposed to write it myself?

The project consists of an EJB module and a Swing client module. No web-module!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I faced the same problem (just a different project name).

```
"compile-test-single" does not exist in the project "ShoppingCart". It is used from target "profile-test-single".BUILD FAILED (total time: 0 seconds)
```

You can do the following to overcome the above error.

1. Find the path of the build.xml file (usually it will be `Workspace\Project\build.xml`)
2. Open the file (make a backup of the file as a part of emergency).
3. Find the Line containing

   ```
   import file="nbproject/profiler-build-impl.xml"
   ```
4. Delete the above line.
5. Save the `build.xml`
6. Run your project again.

Comment: Unfortunately, I moved on from that job and can no longer verify if this would solve it :( But I suppose it will, and I'll accept it.